# Car Steering - OpenGL

Tags: java, algorithm, opengl

I'm creating a racing car game and am having trouble figuring out how to get steering to work. I have a basic race 2D race course that is built in a 3D environment. The program only uses x and y, with z being 0.

My race course consists of a road that is 29 units wide in the x-axis and two long tracks that are 120 units long in the y direction. At 120 units in the y-axis there is a 180 degree turn. You can think of the course as looking similar to a nascar styled race course.

I'm trying to set my car's steering so that it can turn realistically when I reach the 180 degree turns. I'm using two variables that separately control the x / y positions, as well as two variables for the x / y velocities. My code at the moment is as follows:

```
public void steering(){
    double degreesPerFrame = 180 / (2*30); //180 degrees over 30 fps in 2s
    velocityX = velocityX * -1 * Math.cos(degreesPerFrame);
    velocityY = velocityY * -1 * Math.sin(degreesPerFrame);
    double yChange = Math.sin(degreesPerFrame) * velocityY;
    double xChange = Math.cos(degreesPerFrame) * velocityX;
    x += xChange; //change x position
    y += yChange; //change y position
}
```

I'm not completely sure how I can get my steering to turn properly. I'm stuck at the moment and not sure what I would need to change in my function to get steering working properly.

Comment: what is this doing ?velocityX = velocityX * -1 * Math.cos(degreesPerFrame);
    velocityY = velocityY * -1 * Math.sin(degreesPerFrame);

Comment: How does it currently *not* work properly?

Comment: I'm trying to set what the velocities in the x and y directions are. I wasn't sure if I should be doing that in the steering or leave my velocities untouched in steering and have them just as a constant variable elsewhere.

Comment: if you just have velocity without an x and y velocity cos and sin will tell you haw much x and y to add

Comment: so like 
    double yChange = Math.sin(degreesPerFrame) * velocity;
    double xChange = Math.cos(degreesPerFrame) * velocity;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be easier if you don't use angles at all for you calculations. Simply operate with position, velocity, and acceleration vectors.

First, a quick reminder from physics 101. With a small time step `dt`, current position `p`, and current velocity vector `v`, and an acceleration vector `a`, the new position `p'` and velocity vector `v'` are:

```
v' = v + a * dt
p' = p + v' * dt
```

The acceleration `a` depends on the driver input. For example:

- When moving ahead at a constant speed, it is 0.
- When accelerating, it is limited by engine power and tire grip in longitudinal direction.
- When turning, it is limited by tire grip in lateral direction.
- When braking, it is limited by tire grip (mostly, the brakes are typically strong enough to not be a limit).

For a relatively simple model, you can assume that grip in longitudinal and lateral direction are the same (which is not entirely true in reality), which limits the total acceleration to a vector within a circle, which is commonly called the friction circle.

That was mainly just background. Back to the more specific case here, which is turning at a steady speed. The result of steering the car can be modeled by a lateral force, and corresponding acceleration. So in this case, we can apply an acceleration vector that is orthogonal to the current velocity vector.

With the components of the velocity vector:

```
v = (vx, vy)
```

a vector that points orthogonally to the left (you mentioned NASCAR, so there's only left turns...) of this is:

```
(-vy, vx)
```

Since we want to control the amount of lateral acceleration, which is the length of the acceleration vector, we normalize this vector, and multiply it by the maximum acceleration:

```
a = aMax * normalize(-vy, vx)
```

If you use real units for your calculations, you can apply a realistic number for the maximum lateral acceleration `aMax`. Otherwise, just tweak it to give you the desired maneuverability for the car in your artificial units.

That's really all you need. Recapping the steps in code form:

```
// Realistic value for sports car on street tires when using
// metric units. 10 m/s^2 is slightly over 1 g.
static const float MAX_ACCELERATION = 10.0f;

float deltaTime = ...;  // Time since last update.
float accelerationX = -veclocityY;
float accelerationY = velocityX;
float accelerationScale = MAX_ACCELERATION /
        sqrt(accelerationX * accelerationX + accelerationY * accelerationY);
accelerationX *= accelerationScale;
acceleration *= accelerationScale;
velocityX += accelerationX * deltaTime;
velocityY += accelerationY * deltaTime;
x += velocityX * deltaTime;
y += velocityY * deltaTime;
```